# SSH Keys management

Tags: ssh

So I wanted to gain SSH access to my VPS and the customer support told me that I have to add a SSH Private key of the server to my SSH client like (
`ssh-add private_key.txt` ) this and after that I could access the SSH server with my computer but there was a problem.

I couldn't push into any other repository accept the VPS.

So I read a question that explained how can I manage multiple keys on one system, and I configured ( `~/.ssh/config` ) something like this

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git 
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host bitbucket
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_key 
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host something
    HostName somevps.something
    Port 12345
    User someuser
```

But I still cannot push to the other repositories like **bitbucket** or **github** but I can only push to **something** for which I have already added the private key to my SSH client.

I'm almost sure that this is the keys management issue but I cannot see why it is not working.

**UPDATE**
`ssh -T github -v`

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/naveen/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/naveen/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.113] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.255.113 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
```

And nothing else happens

Comment: The sample config above does not reflect what you are saying - the something that should work has no reference to the ssh key location. Please post your full config file exactly as is

Comment: @TomEus I have updated the config and yes **something** does not have any reference to the SSH key location, but it still works file, I can access the server and push to the VPS, I assume it's using the default key and that was the intention in not specifying the SSH key location

Comment: I think that something in this case does not use the SSH key for auth but rather username and password. I would bet that if you access "something" from another computer with the same config, without any key it will work as well

Comment: @TomEus `something` does use the SSH key I added the `something` server's `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to my SSH client. and it does not use `username and password`

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your public key to the BitBucket or GitHub web site, and associate it with your account. Then your `git` client will be able to log into those services.

See:

http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: I'm aware of this and I'm using doing exectly this but still can't push to other repositories, I know how to do this but still there is a problem that is why I asked the question

Comment: We will need to see your log or command output with error messages. Use the verbose flag.